# How do I implement a TextChanging property on a TextBox?

Tags: vb.net, events, textbox

I figured there would be a question like this already, but I didn't have any luck searching. I saw a question where someone asked the same thing but the answer was to use the TextChanged event. That's not what I want though.

TextBox has an event for TextChanged that occurs after the Text property has been changed. I need my control to raise an event before the Text property is actually changed to validate data. If it is valid the Text can be changed, if it is not valid the Text does not get changed.

Here's what I tried:

```
Public Class TextChangingEventArgs
  Inherits System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs

  Private p_sNewValue As String 

  Public Sub New()
    p_sNewValue = String.Empty
  End Sub

  Public Sub New(sNewValue As String)
    p_sNewValue = sNewValue
  End Sub

  Public Property NewValue As String
    Get
      Return p_sNewValue
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
      p_sNewValue = value
    End Set
  End Property
End Class

Public Class BetterTextBox
  Inherits TextBox

  Public Event TextChanging(sender As Object, e As TextChangingEventArgs)

  Public Overrides Property Text As String
    Get
      Return MyBase.Text
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
      Dim e As New TextChangingEventArgs(value)
      RaiseEvent TextChanging(Me, e)
      If e.Cancel = False Then
        MyBase.Text = value
      End If
    End Set
  End Property 
End Class
```

My in my Form I handle the TextChanging event:

```
Private Sub BetterTextBox1_TextChanging(sender As System.Object, e As TextChangingEventArgs) Handles BetterTextBox1.TextChanging
  e.Cancel = Not Regex.IsMatch(e.NewValue, REGEX_PATTERN)
End Sub
```

This works for programmatically setting the Text value of the BetterTextBox control, but it does not work when you are typing into the text box.

Does anyone know what I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: Whatever this is too annoying. I'll just handle it in the TextChanged event and keep a local copy of the last valid value. If the string is not valid in TextChanged I'll just restore it to the previous valid value.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already inheriting from TextBox, you can override WndProc and check for paste messages. This should resolve the right-click > Paste problem. You could then handle "regular," typed text in KeyPressed or KeyDown, as others have suggested.
Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
Private Const WM_PASTE As Integer = &H302
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    If m.Msg = WM_PASTE AndAlso Clipboard.ContainsText() AndAlso ShouldAllowPaste(Clipboard.GetText()) Then
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    ElseIf m.Msg <> WM_PASTE Then
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    If m.Msg = 8465 Then
        If HIWORD(m.WParam) = 1024 Then
            ' raise your TextChanging event
        End If
    End If

    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub

Public Function HIWORD(ByVal n As Integer) As UInteger
    Return CUInt(n >> 16) And CUInt(&HFFFF)
End Function
```

Comment: What is the purpose of checking hiword on wparam?

Answer (score 0):

Try the `KeyPress` event of the Textbox instead.

**EDIT** : to disable right-click in the Textbox, you can do something like this. 
Put this code inside the Textbox's `MouseDown` event.

```
If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
    MessageBox.Show("can't paste!")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

however I noticed you could still paste text using the key combination Ctrl + V. You can write this code to stop that in the `KeyPress` event.

```
If Keys.ControlKey And Keys.V Then
       MessageBox.Show("can't paste!")
       Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Then what about right clicking in the text box and choose Paste in the context menu? I did this because I want to avoid KeyPress. It's just not good enough. It also won't work with other input methods like voice-to-text.

Comment: edited the answer to prevent using the context menu inside the Textbox.

Comment: I don't want to remove functionality that users might want. I just want the control do what I want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you should try with keydown event. It occurs before textchanged or even before 
 keypress.

Comment: That wouldn't work with pasting text into the control, or using any other input method that doesn't involve keys, like voice-to-text.